# What kind of query in LINQ do I have to make to get a custom List that contains Lists of objects?

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

What I'm trying to do is to find the best and fastest way to obtain a collection of objects from a query so I can parse them into JSON and send them through a WCF webservice. I have an entity that is related to two other entities, the properties as shown in my edmx are like this:

- Event

  - EventId
  - Date
  - Acceleration
  - Intensity
  - DeviceId
  - BlockId
  - Device
  - Block
- Device

  - DeviceId
  - Alias
  - ClusterId
  - Cluster
  - Events
- Block

  - BlockId
  - DateStart
  - DateEnd
  - Events

What I want to get List of Lists of the Events associated to every Block, each Block's Events being represented by a List, but I only want to get the EventId, Date, DeviceId, BlockId, Acceleration and Intensity of every Event, because I want to avoid the circular reference that would be caused for trying to parse the Device and Block properties in each Event object.

I tried something like

```
var result = (from d in context.Block select (d.Events)).ToList();
```

but this only returns a List containing Event objects in every Block, but I don't know how to get the information I specified of every Event in every Block.

How can I specify in my query the information I want to retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier using Method Based query:

```
var result = context.Block.Select(b => b.Events.Select(e => new
                                                {
                                                    e.EventId,
                                                    e.Date,
                                                    e.DeviceId,
                                                    e.BlockId,
                                                    e.Accelleration,
                                                    e.Intensity
                                                }).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it creates a List with anonymous types, which cannot be sent through the webservice, I changed the `e=>new{e.EventId,e.Date,e.DeviceId,e.BlockId,e.Accelleration,e.Intensity}` to `e=>new Events{EventId=e.EventId,Date=e.Date,DeviceId=e.DeviceId,BlockId=e.BlockId,Accelleration=e.Accelleration,Intensity=e.Intensity}` but got [this](http://pastebin.com/wqPYG5rZ) exception

Comment: I solved this by converting the result into a string with JavaScriptSerializer and then parsing it into a List<List<Eventos>> list, your answer lead me to this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a groupJoin

Here is an example

> var teamsandriders = teams.GroupJoin(riders, Team => Team.name, Rider
>   => Rider.TeamName, (team, teamRiders) => new {Team = team.name, riders = teamRiders.Select(rider => rider.name)});

Comment: this works but I can't return this in a function since it's a List of anonymous objects I can't send it through the webservice, I tried this `var result = context.Blocks.GroupJoin(context.Events, Block=> Block.BlockId , Event => Event.Block, (block, blockEvents) => new Blocks{ BlockId = block.BlockId  , Events = blocksEvents.Select(event=> new { Date = event.Date , Intensity= event.Intensity, Acceleration= event.Acceleration, EventId = event.EventId }) });` but it says I can't asign a IEnumerable type to a ICollection type.